# Proper why to bind a function with parameters to child component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am still new to React Native and I struggle a bit with the programming paradigm. What I am trying to do (by following the structure of another React.js project) is to create a container (parent component) which contains a number of other components. My ultimate goal is to pass and handle all of the props in the parent component. Child component only shows them. My structure looks something like this:

```
export default class TemporaryCardRequestScreen extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.showDateTimePicker = this.showDateTimePicker.bind(this);
        this.hideDateTimePicker = this.hideDateTimePicker.bind(this);
        this.handleDatePicked = this.handleDatePicked.bind(this);

        this.state.fromDateTime = {
            isVisible: false,
            value: new Date()
        }
    }

    showDateTimePicker = () => { /*body*/ };

    hideDateTimePicker = () => { /*body*/ };

    handleDatePicked = date => { /*body*/ };

    render() {
        return (
            <DateTimePickerComponent 
                isVisible={this.state.fromDateTime.isVisible}
                onConfirmPressed={this.handleDatePicked}
                onCancelPressed={this.hideDateTimePicker}
                showDateTimePicker={this.showDateTimePicker}
                value={this.state.fromDateTime.value}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

and the, my child component looks something like this:

```
// npm ref.: https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker
export default class DateTimePickerComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const {  
            isVisible,
            onConfirmPressed,
            onCancelPressed,
            showDateTimePicker } = this.props;

        return (
            <>
            <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={showDateTimePicker} />
            <DateTimePicker
                isVisible={isVisible}
                onConfirm={onConfirmPressed}
                onCancel={onCancelPressed}
                mode='datetime'
                is24Hour={false}
                date={new Date()}
            />
        </>
      );
    }
  }
```

My focus now is on

```
onConfirmPressed={this.handleDatePicked}
```

currently, **this.handleDatePicked** accepts a single argument but I'd like it to accept one additional which is passed to it at the place being used in child component.

So, my ultimate goal would be to have something similar to this:

```
render() {
        const {  
            isVisible,
            onConfirmPressed,
            onCancelPressed,
            showDateTimePicker,
            dateTimePickerId } = this.props;

        return (
            <>
            <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={this.showDateTimePicker} />
            <DateTimePicker
                isVisible={isVisible}
                onConfirm={onConfirmPressed(dateTimePickerId)}
                onCancel={onCancelPressed}
                mode='datetime'
                is24Hour={false}
                date={new Date()}
            />
        </>
      );
    }
```

So, in this way, in my parent component I could have a single method which can handle the updates for a number of date time pickers in my container (This is actually my use-case). Instead of having the same type of handlers (with different property name) for pretty much the same thing.

**UPDATE:** [Snack expo](https://snack.expo.io/HkZ1xdap4)

Comment: `onConfirm={() => onConfirmPressed(dateTimePickerId)}` maybe? Also, you shouldn't define your state properties as you do in the parent component. Define your state and add the needed properties. `this.state = {foo: "bar"}`

Comment: Okay, I have a form (container) which has a number of components with their own properties. I am not using Redux or anything like this. How do I get the values for all of the components when submitting my form (parent component)?

Comment: Can't you keep those values as state properties in your form container and update them via some callback functions? If you can please share a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). So, people can see your code and help to fix it.

Comment: @devserkan I think that's exactly what I am doing.

Comment: So, for testing purposes as I said fix your state definition and try your callback functions. I can't understand the problem here. If you want to pass some parameter to your callback functions you can do it as I suggested in my first comment. Again, a "mvce" would be great.

Comment: Okay, I just updated my answer and I believe now I have "mvce"

Comment: like @devserkan said, just use `onConfirm={() => onConfirmPressed(dataTimePickerId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture 'onConfirm' of DateTimePickerComponent, then call parent function and pass in the dateTimePickerId.

TemporaryCardRequestScreen

```
// Modify to accept 2 arguments
handleDatePicked = (id, date) => { 
    if (id == "1") {
        // code here
    }
    else if (id == "2") {
        // code here
    } 
};
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <DateTimePickerComponent 
                isVisible={this.state.fromDateTime.isVisible}
                onConfirmPressed={this.handleDatePicked}
                onCancelPressed={this.hideDateTimePicker}
                showDateTimePicker={this.showDateTimePicker}
                value={this.state.fromDateTime.value}
                dateTimePickerId="1"
            />
            <DateTimePickerComponent 
                isVisible={this.state.fromDateTime.isVisible}
                onConfirmPressed={this.handleDatePicked}
                onCancelPressed={this.hideDateTimePicker}
                showDateTimePicker={this.showDateTimePicker}
                value={this.state.fromDateTime.value}
                dateTimePickerId="2}
            />
        </div>

        );
    }
```

DateTimePickerComponent

```
onMyCustomConfirmPressed = (date) => {
    // Parent onConfirmPressed() shall accept 2 arguments
    this.props.onConfirmPressed(this.props.dateTimePickerId, date)
}

render() {
    const {  
        isVisible,
        onConfirmPressed,
        onCancelPressed,
        showDateTimePicker,
        dateTimePickerId } = this.props;

    return (
        <>
        <Button title="Show DatePicker" onPress={this.showDateTimePicker} />
        <DateTimePicker
            isVisible={isVisible}
            onConfirm={this.onMyCustomConfirmPressed}
            onCancel={onCancelPressed}
            mode='datetime'
            is24Hour={false}
            date={new Date()}
        />
        </>
    );
}
```

Comment: I accept your answer because it works, but I was wondering if there's no better shorter option without the need to create my own custom method in the child component. Maybe inline: onConfirm={(date) => this.props.onConfirmPressed(this.props.dateTimePickerId, date)}

Comment: Your above inline function would work just as fine if you feels it has better readability. It's of personal preference.